# Using a Single Web Crawler to Scrape Multiple websites in a predefined format with attachments?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a list of approx. 52 websites which lead to about approx. 150 webpages that i require scraping on. Based on my ignorance and lack of research i started building crawlers per webpage which is starting to become to difficult to complete and maintain.

Based on my analysis thus far I already know what information i want to scrape per webpage and it is clear that these websites have their own structure. On the plus side i noticed that each website has some commonalities in their web structure among their webpages.
My million dollar question, is there a single technique or single web crawler that i can use to scrape these sites? I already know the information that I want, these sites are rarely updated in terms of their web structure and most of these sites have documents that need to be downloaded.

Alternatively, is there a better solution to use that will reduce the amount of web crawlers that I need to build? additionally, these web crawlers will only be used to download the new information of the websites that i am aiming them at.

Answer (score 0):

> […] i started building crawlers per webpage which is starting to become to difficult to complete and maintain […] it is clear that these websites have their own structure. […] these sites are rarely updated in terms of their web structure […]

If websites have different structures, having separate spiders makes sense, and should make maintenance easier in the long term.

You say completing new spiders (I assume you mean developing them, not crawling or something else) is becoming difficult, however if they are similar to an existing spider, you can simply copy-and-paste the most similar existing spider, and make only the necessary changes.

Maintenance should be easiest with separate spiders for different websites. If a single website changes, you can fix the spider for that website. If you have a spider for multiple websites, and only one of them changes, you need to make sure that your changes for the modified website do not break the rest of the websites, which can be a nightmare.

Also, since you say website structures do not change often, maintenance should not be that hard in general.

If you notice you are repeating a lot of code, you might be able to extract some shared code into a spider middleware, a downloader middleware, an extension, an item loader, or even a base spider class shared by two or more spiders. But I would not try to use a single Spider subclass to scrape multiple different websites that are likely to evolve separately.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you crawl specific tags such as `body`, `h1`,`h2`,`h3`,`h4`,`h5`, `h6`,`p` and... for each links. You can gather all `p` tags and append them into a specific link. It can be used for each tags you want to crawl them. Also, you can append related links of tags to your database.